# Selecting two columns based on active cell?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to do conditional formatting on a long range of columns in groups of 2. Im not sure how record a macro that would select the entire column from the active cell and the column next to it, then apply the conditional formating. Then move two cells down and repeat.

This is what I have so far but it would keep going back to those specific cells, I need it to move to the right 2.

```
Sub findDups()
'
' findDups Macro

    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("M1").Select

    Worksheets("User Check List").Activate
    Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.Select` but a better method would not involve using `ActiveCell` or `Selection` method except maybe for initial input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to get you started. I avoid using `Selection` at all, and only use `ActiveCell` as a means of knowing where to *start* the macro. Preferably, you could do that with an `Application.InputBox` but that's not a big deal.

Because I don't know how many times you want this to loop, I used a `Do ... Loop` statement, and this will continue until the column number > 26.  You can change that in the `Loop Until ...` statement.

```
Sub findDups()
Dim startCell As Range
Dim formatCols As Range

Set startCell = ActiveCell

Do
    Set formatCols = startCell.Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn

    formatCols.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    formatCols.FormatConditions(formatCols.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    formatCols.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With formatCols.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With formatCols.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Set startCell = startCell.Offset(0, 2)

Loop Until startCell.Column >= 26

End Sub
```

Here is an example of the output formatting:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you. I have around 400 columns (200 pairs). Is there a way to slightly alter the formula to apply if there's content in the cells instead of changing 26 to 400? The lists start at row 2 and row 1 has headers, maybe something like if row 1 has header run this function :/

Comment: Assuming the sheet contains only these columns of data, no matter how many columns there may be, you could do something like `Loop Until startCell.Column > ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`.  It can still be done if your sheet contains other data, too, but if that's the case I would need to know more about the layout of the sheet in order to programmatically derive the last column to which this should apply.

Comment: I'll try that. The sheet doesn't contain anything else. Just looks like what you have but with headers in Row 1.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if there was a way to limit the number of rows this gets applied to based on whether there's content within the cells. I feel like it's getting applied to the entire column and it's really slowing down the sheet. Maybe instead of the entire column, like the first 100 cells?

Comment: Also, whenever I enter data in the cell, the sheet hangs for a good enough of time.

Comment: Try changing to `set formatcols = startcell.resize(100, 2)` this will do only the first 100 rows.  That should speed it up considerably.